# How to delete superclass entity whose subclass entity has been removed in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, subclass, entitymanager, superclass

There are two entity classes A and B, and instances a, b (a and b have same id). B is subclass of A ( B extends A). I removed an entity "b" from database. Then, I saw that "a" has not been deleted. Actually that s what I really want. However at some point of my code, I want to remove "a" too. But when I do entityManager.remove(a) then it throws exception saying, detached entity can t be removed. It seems removing a subclass entity makes superclass entity detached although superclass entity remains in database. Can anybody help me to remove instance a.

Note: a and b have same ids because when I create b, automatically a is created with the same id ( rule of inheritance).

Comment: In fact there is only one entity b that is represented by two records in table a and b. How did you remove the b record?

Comment: Thanks for reply,I deleted with native sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `session.delete(b)`. This deletes both records from your database.

After having deleted the b record with a native SQL delete statement, you have to delete the a record accordingly with a native delete statement.